# java.io.File mkdirs() method throws NullPointerException on Windows when path not starts with driveletter

Tags: java, windows, filesystems, java-io

When File class mkdirs() is used to create two sub directories in a path with no drive letter at the start NullPointerException is thrown. Where as if I create one sub directory this works perfectly with no errors.

When the path starts with the drive letter sub directories are created to any level.

**How can I write unique code for both windows and unix file system in this case?**

Here are the examples:

*C:/apps directory already exists.*

```
//scenario 1    
String ITERATION_DIR = "/apps"+"/"+"iter05";
            File iterationDir = new File(ITERATION_DIR);
            if(!iterationDir.exists()){
                iterationDir.mkdirs();  //creates iter05 directory
            }
    //scenario 2
           ITERATION_DIR = "/apps"+"/"+"iter05"+"/"+"ENG";
            iterationDir = new File(ITERATION_DIR);
            if(!iterationDir.exists()){
                iterationDir.mkdirs(); //creates ENG directory
            }

//scenario 3
            ITERATION_DIR = "/apps"+"/"+"iter05"+"/"+"ENG/dir1/dir2/dir3";
            iterationDir = new File(ITERATION_DIR);
            if(!iterationDir.exists()){
                iterationDir.mkdirs();  //throws exception.
            }

//scenario 4
            ITERATION_DIR = "C:/apps"+"/"+"iter05"+"/"+"ENG/dir1/dir2/dir3";
            iterationDir = new File(ITERATION_DIR);
            if(!iterationDir.exists()){
                iterationDir.mkdirs();  //creates dir1/dir2/dir3 when path is prefixed with drive letter
            }
```

Exception details for scenario 3:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.normalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:82)
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.getUserPath(WinNTFileSystem.java:346)
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.resolve(WinNTFileSystem.java:311)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(File.java:643)
    at java.io.File.mkdirs(File.java:1348)
```

Comment: I tried your code and it works for me. Maybe you are having a similar problem to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584750/jfilechooser-fails. I added ``System.clearProperty("user.dir");`` to the start of your code and then I see the same exception you are getting.